# How to compare two csv files in UNIX and create delta ( modified/ new records )

Tags: unix, awk

I have two csv files old.csv and new.csv. I need only new or updated records from new.csv file. Delete records from new.csv if that is exists in old.csv.

**old.csv**

```
"R","abc","london","1234567"
"S","def","london","1234567"
"T","kevin","boston","9876"
"U","krish","canada","1234567"
```

**new.csv**

```
"R","abc","london","5678"
"S","def","london","1234567"
"T","kevin","boston","9876"
"V","Bell","tokyo","2222"
```

**Output in new.csv**

```
"R","abc","london","5678"     
"V","Bell","tokyo","2222"
```

**Note : if All records are same in new.csv then new.csv should be empty**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use for example `grep`:

```
$ grep -v -f old.csv new.csv # > the_new_new.csv 
"R","abc","london","5678"
"V","Bell","tokyo","2222"
```

and:

```
$ grep -v -f old.csv old.csv
$                            # see, no differencies in 2 identical files
```

`man grep`:

```
  -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)

  -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
```

**Then again, you could use awk for it:**

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' old.csv new.csv
"R","abc","london","5678"
"V","Bell","tokyo","2222"
```

Explained:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{            # the records in the first file are hashed to memory
    a[$0]
    next
} 
!($0 in a)          # the records which are not found in the hash are printed
' old.csv new.csv   # > the_new_new.csv
```

Comment: Your answer without an `awk`? Weird :), also I think we should add this as part of the `awk` Wiki FAQ, there is a question of this sort every day of the week! May be Ed Morton can have a say in this.

Comment: The awk solution is much faster.

Answer (score 5):

When the files are sorted:

```
comm -13 old.csv new.csv
```

When they are not sorted, and sorting is allowed:

```
comm -13 <(sort old.csv) <(sort new.csv)
```